# Subtracting Two Times On Different Days Give Incorrect Number of Days Elapsed

Tags: datetime, google-sheets

I want to find the amount of time passed between 2/6/2023 5:03:00 and 2/8/2023 19:00:00 by subtracting the earlier date from the later date and adjusting the output formatting.

This is what I tried, and I expected to see 2 day 13 hours and 57 minutes but the output contained only 1 day instead.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Starting Time | Ending Time | Difference |
| 2/6/2023 5:03 AM | 2/8/2023 7:00 PM | 00 years 1 days 13 hours 57 minutes |

C2 has the formula `=B2-A2`

I applied formatting to the output in column C as shown below.

`Y "years" D "days" H "hours" M "minutes"`

Answer (score 1):

It's considering the date as DD/MM/YYYY, then the difference is 61.58125 days, which is equal to 2 months, 1 day and so on. Since you weren't displaying months you couldn't see the difference

Please check the locale and/or the date format prior to inserting the dates and the calculations should work

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that the dates in Columns A & B are getting read as DD/MM/YYYY instead of MM/DD/YYYY (assuming the dates entered are 6-Feb-2023 and 8-Feb-2023 in Columns A & B respectively).

You could change the formatting of those two cells to MM/DD/YYYYY so that the dates entered are read properly. And hence the calculated value in Column C would display the correct value.